# Why can't I use my printer even though my computer says that software and drivers are installed

Tags: windows-7, all-in-one, print-drivers

I have downloaded drivers from Canon, Kodak, and HP on three separate printers and my computer will not complete install or gives me "printer not detected. I've have tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Please include the exact error, the make/model of printer and perhaps some screen shots of what goes wrong.

Comment: I always start with the basics, it sound like a physical connection problem, are the lights on at the physical printer?

Answer (score 1):

You're not being super clear/detailed, but it sounds like you might have been a bit rash. You're installing 3 printers at the same time? I suggest you go slowly.

Remove every single printer driver you've put, and then plug in one printer, turn it on and see what Windows does. If Windows manages to install it fine and it works, great. If not, look for the driver on the maker's website. Try to get this one printer to work. Only when it does should you try to install the second one.

Repeat with the rest of the printers, one at a time. Always try to make it work "naked", just with Windows, and only resort to manually installing drivers if it doesn't work.

If really, you can't get anything to work at all, I suggest you plug them all in (one by one), turn them all on and try a third-party software that will scan all the hardware in your computer and look for the appropriate, up-to-date drivers. This can help you go around driver mistakes or faulty installers.

You can pick one from here: http://alternativeto.net/software/driver-genius/

If it still doesn't work, please give more information about your problem: how it occurred, what you mean by install not completing, what you did, etc.